# XGBoost Python error: "Size of labels must equal to number of rows"

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost

I am using xgboost in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df=pd.read_csv('442.csv')
y=df.columnone
X=df.columnfive

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=Y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=Y_test)
```

The shape of the label seem to be uniform with the training set?

```
X_train.shape
>(405020,)
Y_train.shape
>(405020,)

param = {
   'eta': 0.3,
   'max_depth': 3, 
   'objective': 'multi:softprob', 
   'num_class': 2}
steps = 20  # The number of training iterations
```

But running this gives me this result:

```
model = xgb.train(param, dtrain, steps)
>XGBoostError: Check failed: labels_.Size() == num_row_ (405020 vs. 1) : Size of labels must equal to number of rows.
```

When I run

```
dtrain.num_row()
>1
dtrain.num_col()
>405020
```

This might have to do with the error? But I still have no idea how that could have happened. My initial X and y variables both have the correct number of rows and one column each.

Answer (score 3):

`Xgboost` expects a 2-d array of inputs, and a vector of outputs. You are giving it two vectors, so it is confused. using `df[["columnone"]]` for the input should work.

Comment: Thanks. After changing that, though, I still get the same error. I changed it to `y=df[["columnone"]]` but still get the same result. The only difference is that this returns a different result: 
```Y_train.shape
>(405020,1)``` 
I added another bit of information I found in the original post, which I don't know is relevant or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but it was because I had a bug in my code

```py
x = trainset[feature_cols + dummy_var_cols]
y = testset[[label_column]]

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_with_dummies, y)
```

Can you spot it? My `y` variable was coming from my test set and not my train set!